# How to extract substrings from a masked Python string?

Tags: python, string, parsing

I'm writing an HTTP Request Handler with intuitive routing. My goal is to be able to apply a decorator to a function which states the HTTP method being used as well as the path to be listened on for executing the decorated function. Here's a sample of this implementation:

```
@route_handler("GET", "/personnel")
def retrievePersonnel():
    return personnelDB.retrieveAll()
```

However, I also want to be able to add variables to the path. For example, `/personnel/3` would fetch a personnel with an ID of 3. The way I want to go about doing this is providing a sort of 'variable mask' to the path passed into the route_handler. A new example would be:

```
@route_handler("GET", "/personnel/{ID}")
def retrievePersonnelByID(ID):
    return personnelDB.retrieveByID(ID)
```

The decorator's purpose would be to compare the path literal (`/personnel/3` for example) with the path 'mask' (`/personnel/{ID}`) and pass the 3 into the decorated function. I'm assuming the solution would be to compare the two strings, keep the differences, and place the difference in the literal into a variable named after the difference in the mask (minus the curly braces). But then I'd also have to check to see if the literal matches the mask minus the `{}` variable catchers...

---

tl;dr - is there a way to do

`stringMask("/personnel/{ID}", "/personnel/5") -> True, {"ID": 5}`

`stringMask("/personnel/{ID}", "/flowers/5") -> False, {}`

`stringMask("/personnel/{ID}", "/personnel") -> False, {}`

Comment: This is almost exactly what a [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) app looks like, why don't you use that?

Comment: The [`behave` BDD module](http://pythonhosted.org/behave/) uses this approach to detect and define function arguments. You might want to have a look at the source code.

Comment: @jonrsharpe This is homework that I've taken far out of the requirements of the assignment. The minimum is that I _must_ use Python's native http.server module and no libraries. I want to learn how to do the decoration and route variable extraction on my own.

Comment: I haven't tried anything, because I was hoping there was some sort of pre-existing 'correct' way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm guessing there isn't really an easy solution to this, I'm gonna post the solution I did. I was hoping there would be something I could do in a few lines, but oh well ¯_(ツ)_/¯

```
def checkPath(self, mask):
    mask_parts = mask[1:].split("/")
    path_parts = self.path[1:].rstrip("/").split("/")
    if len(mask_parts) != len(path_parts):
        self.urlVars = {}
        return False

    vars = {}
    for i in range(len(mask_parts)):
        if mask_parts[i][0] == "{":
            vars[mask_parts[i][1:-1]] = path_parts[i]
        else:
            if mask_parts[i] != path_parts[i]:
                self.urlVars = {}
                return False

    self.url_vars = vars # save extracted variables
    return True
```

A mask is just a string like one of the ones below:

```
/resource
/resource/{ID}
/group/{name}/resource/{ID}
```